# Почему после конвертации видео с одинаковыми параметрами и продолжительности имеют разный размер?

Tags: видео, ffmpeg, конвертация

Конвертирую с помощью ffmpeg видеофайлы, имеющие одинаковое расширение и продолжительность. 
Задаю такие параметры

```
ffmpeg -i input -ar 22050 -ab 127k -ac 2 -f mp4 -b 700k -s 720x480 -y -g 25 output"
```

На выходе получаю файлы разного размера от 200мб до 400мб. 
С чем это связано?

Comment: А почему вдруг они должны иметь одинаковый размер? Даже разные JPEG-фото одного пиксельного размера и с одинаковыми параметрами сжатия имеют разный размер. Степень упаковки зависит от кучи параметров самой картинки. Попробуйте сделать часовое видео с полностью чёрными кадрами, и увидите, как оно запакуется почти в ноль.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Answer (score 4):

> С чем это связано?

с тем, что при конвертации происходит сжатие информации (возможно, просто по другому алгоритму, имеющему иные характеристики, нежели у исходных файлов).

а коэффициент сжатия информации может разительно [отличаться](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F) в зависимости от самой информации.

---

**иллюстрация**. заполним один файл какими-нибудь байтами, а второй файл — нулями:

```
$ dd if=/some/file of=file1 bs=1 count=1M
1048576+0 records in
1048576+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 2.58507 s, 406 kB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file2 bs=1 count=1M1048576+0 records in
1048576+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 2.40829 s, 435 kB/s
```

файлы имеют абсолютно одинаковый размер — один мегабайт:

```
$ stat -c '%n %s' file*
file1 1048576
file2 1048576
```

а теперь сожмём их любым (одинаковым) образом и сравним размеры получившихся сжатых файлов:

```
$ gzip file1
$ gzip file2
$ stat -c '%n %s' file*
file1.gz 1042900
file2.gz 1057
```

размеры получившихся файлов отличаются **почти в тысячу раз**. хотя размер исходных файлов и алгоритм сжатия — абсолютно идентичны.

p.s. размер сжатого первого файла почти не отличается от исходного ввиду того, что в качестве источника байтов я взял уже сжатый файл.